# java associative array sort of thing with more than one data type

Tags: java

imagine this:
`DataTypeForConfigs config`
with
`String` keys, but values of either `String`, `Integer`, or `Boolean`,
in Java, JSON can do that, but I'm making a format That goes along the lines of:

`number "coolness" is 9001` means
`int coolness = 9001;`

It's method is: Read line, read each word, think what to make of it, set it to a Variable within it's reach

Also: what would happen if another thing had its own place to put config? a null would be read? WHY? constructor thinks a file has null on it? Rage face.

Say... should I make a class called `SettingVal` that when given a `getValue()` call it would say what it is?

SO:

`config["Coolness"].getValue();`

`return`'s 9001

WAIT:

How on earth would I make the `getValue()` method? HOW? RETURN VALUE WONT LIKE THIS!! OH CRAP!

Solution:

<s>Another Data type comes in and checks its 'gender' (`String`, `Bool`, `Int`) and then checks it's value of that 'gender' (`strVal`, `boolVar`, `intVar`)</s>

Return values are a big problem when dealing with this. I need a **stress free version**, so maybe I can have a `void` returning method that runs another method based on what data type it is said to hold! Am I right?

I have a temporary solution, `setVar` works, `getVar` is `get*Var`, where * is `Str`, `Bool` or `Int`.

Sadly, I Haven't yet been able to properly read it from a file, the method I made to read from a file is not working. It makes a `Map<String,SettingVar>`, using a `HashMap` constructor and returns that map, but seems whenever I try to access a variable from it that variable is `null`. It is probably because of `IOException`s and `FileNotFoundException`s, `FileNotFound`? Why? It Shouldn't be running until called. Oh, and also `NullPointerException`s Please Help!

SUBQUESTION: what happens when you `MapVariable.put({NAME HERE}, varToPutIn)` many times in a for loop? what about `MapVariable.put({NAME HERE},new ...)`?

My code in links:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/66c4d1c2d2718a4cc9b9

because I don't have enough reputation

P.S: OK! ive made the config reader work now, and `SettingVar`, and `SettingContainer` and im working on `ConfigWriter` which is good, now working on a prototype for a java command prompt like thing, and soon a WHOLE OS!! wait... java is an os. thats why java virtual machine... oh. Well, how can I close this question and turn the outcome into a revolutionary new thingy for kids who want to learn to code java *cough cough* especialy ones with higher learning ability than social ability... and like to hang around with mature people who dont bully them like all the kids in their school. (Wow, that was specific)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a Plain Old Java Object which you can read from JSON.

```
class Config {
    int coolness = 9001;
    String hello = "world";
    boolean cool = true;
}
```

This way you can have fields with a variety of types.

Comment: what is a _"POJO"_

Comment: @Alex-c  It means "Plain Old Java Object."

Comment: BTW can objects EXPAND?? that's what I need!

Comment: @Alex-c you can sub-class them to add fields. You can also add all the possible fields upfront.

Answer (score 0):

The type you're looking for is `Map<String,Object>`, but it is not type-safe and you'll have to do a bunch of casting:

```
Map<String,Object> config = new HashMap<>();
config.put("coolness",9001);
config.put("hello","world");
config.put("cool", true);

boolean cool     = (Boolean) config.get("cool");
String  hello    = (String)  config.get("world");
int     coolness = (Integer) config.get("coolness");
```

Generally, I'd recommend creating a dedicated class for holding your configuration (each field = one property), which is strongly typed and doesn't require casting, and then use something like Jackson to serialize/deserialize it from json, yaml, or xml.

This provides structure to your configuration, and will cause any issues with malformed configurations to show up when you start your application/load your configuration, and not in the middle of your application.

Comment: it gets config values from a file in the same directory, line by line

Comment: @Alex-c - yes, you can write code that would do that.  But this is not a free Java coding service.

Comment: @StephenC - That's what i'm TRYING to do

Comment: error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayList(String[]) when splitting a line into words, funnilly words IS line.split.

Comment: also cannot find symbol errors to do with the `ConfigDecoder` function when in use outside of the class it is in

Comment: ookay, UPDATE: my splitting's results  seem to make the word disappear.

Comment: UPDATE: I have a new splitter that WORKS!

Comment: Great.  But I was expecting you to show us the >>code<< that you have written, not a running commentary of your thought processes (I think) ... which I'm afraid makes no sense to me (the commentary that is (smiley face) not the thought process ... though ... that makes no sense to me either.  OH CRAP!)

Comment: @StephenC - Ive got ALOT of code though, where should I put my code?

Answer (score 0):

> SUBQUESTION: what happens when you `MapVariable.put(varToPutIn)` many times in a for loop?

A Map represents a mapping.  If you do this:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    map.put("myKey", Integer.valueOf(i));
}
```

what happens is that you add a mapping from "myKey" to zero, then update it to one, two, three and so on.  When the loop ends, "myKey" will map to nine.

In short, the map entry for "myKey" is behaving like a variable of type `Integer` that you assign to repeatedly.

Comment: And what happens when you do what is in my gist(s)?

Comment: You see, each key is different, but the value is a variable that gets re-defined

Comment: but... the key is obtained from the variable

Comment: The same thing happens.  Each time you call `put` you update the mapping to whatever the supplied new value is.

Comment: You see, THE KEYS ARE ORIGINAL! THE VALUE IS A VARIABLE THAT GETS RE DEFINED EVERY LOOP OF A LINE

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your Gists are telling me that you simply didn't take on board what @Darth Android wrote.  Rather that hashing through your code, here's a simple way to parse your config file syntax (more or less) and load it into a `Map<String, Object>`

Note: I have not compiled or tested this code.  It is written to be read and understood, rather than borrowed.

```
Map<String,Object> config = new HashMap<>();
try (Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileReader(someFile))) {
    while (s.hasNext()) {

        // Syntax is '<type> <name> is <value>'

        String[] words = s.nextLine().split("\\s+");
        if (words.length != 4 || !words[2].equals("is")) {
            throw MySyntaxException("unrecognizable config");
        }
        String type = words[0];
        String name = words[1];
        String val = words[3];
        switch (type) {
        case "number":
            map.put(name,  Integer.valueOf(val));
            break;
        case "boolean":
            map.put(name,  Boolean.valueOf(val));
            break;
        case "string":
            map.put(name, val);
            break;
        default:
            throw MySyntaxException("unknown type");
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        throw MySyntaxException("invalid number");
    }
}
```

Comment: Illegal Escape character when you use your \s+, OUCH!

Comment: Its ok, I'll use MY splitter

Comment: **"Note: I have not compiled or tested this code. It is written to be read rather than borrowed."**

Comment: yea, also FileNotFoundException when I put in my file. OOF

Comment: Ok, so I merged your code into mine and I think THEY ARE VERY SIMILAR, only I looped through words and I still dont use scanner

Comment: Now it doesnt because my splitter broke dows last second!! FFFFFUUUUUUUUU <- me

Comment: meh, shoot that last comment